# Facebook counter drop to 0 after moving to https

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

Following the instructions given by google folks, I added https support to our blog.

Nginx, behind the scene redirect everything non http to https, proxied to a ruby on rails app.

Everything seems to work quite well but facebook counters appears now buggy.

If you look the source of this page : https://milesandlove.com/argentine/le-fitz-roy
I added a lot of og meta tags :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://milesandlove.com/argentine/le-fitz-roy"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://milesandlove.com/argentine/le-fitz-roy"/>
```

And the share button :

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" fb:like:href="https://milesandlove.com/argentine/le-fitz-roy"></a>
```

Note that even if its a add_this button, it would be exactly the same result with the official facebook one.

**The weird thingis since nobody like the page, it kept showing the old count** . Since a new person came and like the page, it **suddenly reset the counter to 0** !

1. Is the count definately lost ?
2. Why Facebook is protocol aware ?
3. I read that a tricky solution whould be to serve a http:// page to the facebook
   crawler. Is it the only solution ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Essentially you've changed your URL - you might have to contact Facebook in order to "migrate" your likes (if that is even possible).
2. It is 100% possible to serve totally different content on the same domain with different protocols just like `http` differs from `ftp`, `http` can differ from `https`. I would say that this is expected behavior.
3. I don't think that this is a "tricky" solution. There are many cases in which you would want a crawler to see slightly different content from a regular user in a browser. You could set this up to only respond to Facebook by using their specified IP addresses mentioned on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#crawl).

Comment: Thanks you. I'm still disapointed since it appears that when a URL is scrapped once again (via facebook debug) or when a like/share occurs, that reset *definitely* the counter to 0. Any idea to get it back? I mean how a https migration can reset counters in facebook side ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will reset the likes count on your ages when you move to https:// and there's no way around this. I have a 301 redirect on the old URL and Facebook doesn't follow it. It will not keep the old likes and it will treat https:// domain as a separate page. Which is bs really! I don't know of a single site that serves different content on http:// and https://. So, there's no solution to this issue at this stage.